# How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg

I am facing  “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error on my Dell XPS M 1530 dual boot laptop. I referred [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) but not able to fix the problem yet.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

I also verified that greeter is valid.

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

I installed the nvidia driver

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` - More stable/tested version s`udo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates` - More up-to-date version

Still when I tried to reboot in safe mode it did not help.

if I run startx from command line I see the error
Module Nvidia_173 not found.
No screens found.

Any thoughts on how can I fix this. Thanks.

Edit:
@private: could you please tell how can I verify if nvidia has optimus or not.

Comment: does your nvidia have optimus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting the file `~/.Xauthority` and rebooting fixed the problem for me.

To do this, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, log in with your username/password & then run these commands:

`rm ~/.Xauthority`

`sudo reboot`